# Getting the highest date from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of objects with date properties, and using Linq, I want to return the latest date.

Normal C# Code.

```
List<ProjectMetric> A= _projectMetric.AggregateProjectMetrics;
_measure = A[0].Measures.GetCurrentMeasure();
string m = _measure.DateMeasured.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

I tried getting the latest date using the following, without success, using the OrderByDescending function:

```
IEnumerable<ProjectMetric> lm = A.OrderByDescending(s => s.Measures.GetCurrentMeasure());
_measure=lm.First().Measures.GetCurrentMeasure();
if (_measure != null)
{
    string m = _measure.DateMeasured.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
    tblCell.InnerText = m;
}
```

Here, I get the date for the 1st item in the List, because I did A[0]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you apply `OrderByDescending(s => s.DateMeasured)`?

Comment: @user1989 please see my answer. The OrderByDescending should be based on the `DateMeasured` and not on the `GurrentMeasure`.

Comment: @Christos In my solution, sometime there is a condition where _measure = projectMetricList[0].Measures.GetCurrentMeasure(); returns null value. So, here with your solution when there is a value it works but when there is no value i get that null object reference error.

Answer (score 1):

To get your highest date, use:

```
DateTime maxDate = _projectMetric
                     .AggregateProjectMetrics
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateMeasured)
                     .Select(x => x.DateMeasured)
                     .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxDate = A[0].Measures.Max(x => x.DateMeasured);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, here's some psuedocode:

```
HighestDate = _projectMetric.AggregateProjectMetrics.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateMeasured).Select(x => x.DateMeasured).FirstOrDefault()
```

or

```
HighestDate = (from x in _projectMetric.AggregateProjectMetrics OrderBy x.DateMeasured descending select x.DateMeasured).FirstOrDefault();
```